# My If-statements seem to be ignored even though my variables look fine in the debugger

Tags: c

I just started learning C (I'm an absolute beginner) and I'm trying to make a program that translates Roman numbers to Arabic and vice versa.

If I were to type "IX" my program should give me a "9" as an output but instead I get a "1".  I tried to find the issue on my own using the debugger and I can see my program entering the first If-Statement

```
if (userString[localIndex] == 'I')
```

but then it skips the inner If-Statement

```
else if (userString[++localIndex] == 'X') {
                    ARABIC_NUM += 9;
                    localIndex++;
                }
```

I'm not sure why this is happening. If I type "IV" my program outputs a "4" which is the correct answer but if I type "IVIV" my programs once again outputs a lonely "4" and ignores the rest of my input.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NOT_A_NUMBER 0
#define IS_ROMAN 1
#define IS_ARABIC 2

int ARABIC_NUM = 0;

int findStringLength(char* userString) {

int stringLength = 0;
size_t index = 0;

while (userString[index] != '\0')
{
    if (userString[index] != '\0') {
        stringLength++;
        index++;
    }

}

  return stringLength;
}

void resetString(char* userString)
{
size_t stringLength = findStringLength(userString);

for (size_t index = 0; index < stringLength; index++)
{
    userString[index] = '\0';
 }
}

void printString(char* userString)
{
size_t stringLength = findStringLength(userString);

for (size_t index = 0; index < stringLength; index++)
{
    if (userString[index] != '\0')
        printf("~%zu:%c~ ", index, userString[index]);
    else
        printf("Null character");
  }
}

bool ifEnd(char* numberInput, size_t counter) {

bool userEnd = false;

for (size_t index = 0; index < counter; index++)
{
    if ((numberInput[index - 2] == 'E' && numberInput[index - 1] == 'N' && numberInput[index] == 'D')) {
        userEnd = true;
    }
}
return userEnd;
}

int isNumTrue(char userChar) {

int isRoman = NOT_A_NUMBER;
int isArabic = NOT_A_NUMBER;

if (userChar == 'I' || userChar == 'V' || userChar == 'X' || 
userChar == 'L' || userChar == 'C' || userChar == 'D' || userChar == 'M') {

    isRoman = IS_ROMAN;


    return isRoman;

}
else if (userChar == '0' || userChar == '1' || userChar == '2' || userChar == '3' || userChar == '4' || userChar == '5' || userChar == '6' || userChar == '7' || userChar == '8' || userChar == '9') {

    isArabic = IS_ARABIC;

    return isArabic;

}
else {

    return NOT_A_NUMBER;

}

}

void convertToArabic(char* userString, size_t counter) {

for (size_t localIndex = 0; userString[localIndex] != '\0'; localIndex++) {

    // printf("[ %c%s]", userString[localIndex], "-o ");

    if (userString[localIndex] == 'I') {

        if (userString[++localIndex] == 'V') {
            printf("Made it in");
            ARABIC_NUM += 4;
            localIndex++;
        }
        else if (userString[++localIndex] == 'X') {
            ARABIC_NUM += 9;
            localIndex++;
        }
        else {
            ARABIC_NUM += 1;
        }

    }

    else if (userString[localIndex] == 'V') {
        ARABIC_NUM += 5;
    }

    else if (userString[localIndex] == 'X') {

        if (userString[localIndex++] == 'L') {
            ARABIC_NUM += 40;
            localIndex++;
        }
        else if (userString[localIndex++] == 'C') {
            ARABIC_NUM += 90;
            localIndex++;
        }
        else {
            ARABIC_NUM += 10;
        }
    }

    else if (userString[localIndex] == 'L') {
        ARABIC_NUM += 50;
    }

    else if (userString[localIndex] == 'C') {
        if (userString[localIndex++] == 'D') {
            ARABIC_NUM += 400;
            localIndex++;
        }
        else if (userString[localIndex++] == 'M') {
            ARABIC_NUM += 900;
            localIndex++;
        }
        else {
            ARABIC_NUM += 100;
        }
    }

    else if (userString[localIndex] == 'D') {
        ARABIC_NUM += 500;
    }

    else if (userString[localIndex] == 'M') {
        ARABIC_NUM += 1000;
    }

    else {
        printf("Switch default. You shouldn't be seeing this");
    }

    /* else
     {
         printf("[ %c%s]", userString[localIndex],"-x ");
     }*/

}

printf("%s%d%s", "\n Number was :", ARABIC_NUM, "\n");
}

bool convertToRoman(char* userString, char* romanStringHolder, size_t counter) {

bool isValid = true;
int arabicNum = atoi(userString);
char repetitionLimit = '\0';

for (size_t index = 0; arabicNum != 0; index++) {

    /* if ((isNumTrue(userString[index]) == IS_ARABIC || userString[index] == '\n') && index < counter)
     {
         printf("[ %c%s]", userString[index], "-o ");

     }*/
    if (arabicNum >= 4000) {

        do {
            if (romanStringHolder[index - 2] == romanStringHolder[index - 1] == romanStringHolder[index]) {

                repetitionLimit = romanStringHolder[index - 2];

            }
            if (arabicNum / 1000000 >= 1)//&& repetitionLimit != 'M')
            {
                romanStringHolder[index] = 'M';
                arabicNum -= 1000000;
            }
            else if (arabicNum / 900000 >= 1)// && repetitionLimit != 'M')
            {
                romanStringHolder[index] = 'C';
                romanStringHolder[++index] = 'M';
                arabicNum -= 900000;
            }
            else if (arabicNum / 500000 >= 1)// && repetitionLimit != 'D')
            {
                romanStringHolder[index] = 'D';
                arabicNum -= 500000;
            }
            else if (arabicNum / 400000 >= 1)//&& repetitionLimit != 'D')
            {
                romanStringHolder[index] = 'C';
                romanStringHolder[++index] = 'D';
                arabicNum -= 400000;
            }
            else if (arabicNum / 100000 >= 1)// && repetitionLimit != 'C')
            {
                romanStringHolder[index] = 'C';
                arabicNum -= 100000;
            }
            else if (arabicNum / 90000 >= 1)//&& repetitionLimit != 'C')
            {
                romanStringHolder[index] = 'X';
                romanStringHolder[++index] = 'C';
                arabicNum -= 90000;
            }
            else if (arabicNum / 50000 >= 1)// && repetitionLimit != 'L')
            {
                romanStringHolder[index] = 'L';
                arabicNum -= 50000;
            }
            else if (arabicNum / 40000 >= 1)// && repetitionLimit != 'L')
            {
                romanStringHolder[index] = 'X';
                romanStringHolder[++index] = 'L';
                arabicNum -= 40000;
            }
            else if (arabicNum / 10000 >= 1)//&& repetitionLimit != 'X')
            {
                romanStringHolder[index] = 'X';
                arabicNum -= 10000;
            }
            else if (arabicNum / 9000 >= 1)// && repetitionLimit != 'X')
            {
                romanStringHolder[index] = 'I';
                romanStringHolder[++index] = 'X';
                arabicNum -= 9000;
            }
            else if (arabicNum / 5000 >= 1)//&& repetitionLimit != 'V')
            {
                romanStringHolder[index] = 'V';
                arabicNum -= 5000;
            }
            else if (arabicNum / 4000 >= 1)//&& repetitionLimit != 'I')
            {
                romanStringHolder[index] = 'I';
                romanStringHolder[++index] = 'V';
                arabicNum -= 4000;
            }
            else if (arabicNum / 1000 >= 1)// && repetitionLimit != 'I')
            {
                romanStringHolder[index] = 'I';
                arabicNum -= 1000;
            }

            index++;
        } while (arabicNum >= 4000);


        romanStringHolder[index] = '_';
        index++;
    }
    if (arabicNum <= 3999) {
        if (arabicNum / 1000 >= 1)
        {
            romanStringHolder[index] = 'M';
            arabicNum -= 1000;
        }
        if (arabicNum / 900 >= 1)
        {
            romanStringHolder[index] = 'C';
            romanStringHolder[++index] = 'M';
            arabicNum -= 900;
        }
        else if (arabicNum / 500 >= 1)
        {
            romanStringHolder[index] = 'D';
            arabicNum -= 500;
        }
        else if (arabicNum / 400 >= 1)
        {
            romanStringHolder[index] = 'C';
            romanStringHolder[++index] = 'D';
            arabicNum -= 400;
        }
        else if (arabicNum / 100 >= 1)
        {
            romanStringHolder[index] = 'C';
            arabicNum -= 100;
        }
        else if (arabicNum / 90 >= 1)
        {
            romanStringHolder[index] = 'X';
            romanStringHolder[++index] = 'C';
            arabicNum -= 90;
        }
        else if (arabicNum / 50 >= 1)
        {
            romanStringHolder[index] = 'L';
            arabicNum -= 50;
        }
        else if (arabicNum / 40 >= 1)
        {
            romanStringHolder[index] = 'X';
            romanStringHolder[++index] = 'L';
            arabicNum -= 40;
        }
        else if (arabicNum / 10 >= 1)
        {
            romanStringHolder[index] = 'X';
            arabicNum -= 10;
        }
        else if (arabicNum / 9 >= 1)
        {
            romanStringHolder[index] = 'I';
            romanStringHolder[++index] = 'X';
            arabicNum -= 9;
        }
        else if (arabicNum / 5 >= 1)
        {
            romanStringHolder[index] = 'V';
            arabicNum -= 5;
        }
        else if (arabicNum / 4 >= 1)
        {
            romanStringHolder[index] = 'I';
            romanStringHolder[++index] = 'V';
            arabicNum -= 4;
        }
        else if (arabicNum / 1 >= 1)
        {
            romanStringHolder[index] = 'I';
            arabicNum -= 1;
        }

    }

}

if (romanStringHolder > 3999999)

    printf("\n");
return isValid;
 }

 int findNumSystem(char* userString, char* toRomanString) {

//printf(" -%zu and %d-", counter, findStringLength(userString));

size_t counter = findStringLength(userString);

int romanNumAmount = 0;
int arabicNumAmount = 0;
int notNumAmount = 0;

for (size_t localIndex = 0; localIndex < counter; localIndex++) {

    if (isNumTrue(userString[localIndex]) == IS_ROMAN || ((isNumTrue(userString[localIndex - 1]) == IS_ROMAN) && (userString[localIndex] == '\n')))
    {
        printf("[ %c%s]", userString[localIndex], "-R ");


        romanNumAmount++;

        if (romanNumAmount == (findStringLength(userString) - 1)) {
            printf("\nAll Numbers are Roman");
            convertToArabic(userString, counter);
            break;
        }
    }
    else if (isNumTrue(userString[localIndex]) == IS_ARABIC || ((isNumTrue(userString[localIndex - 1]) == IS_ARABIC) && (userString[localIndex] == '\n')))
    {
        printf("[ %c%s]", userString[localIndex], "-A ");

        arabicNumAmount++;

        if (arabicNumAmount == (findStringLength(userString) - 1)) 
    {
            printf("\nAll numbers are Arabic");
            convertToRoman(userString, toRomanString, counter);
            printString(toRomanString);
            break;
        }
    }
    else if (isNumTrue(userString[localIndex]) == NOT_A_NUMBER)
    {
        printf("[ %c%s]", userString[localIndex], "-X ");

        notNumAmount++;
        if (notNumAmount == (findStringLength(userString))) {
            printf("\nNone of the characters is a number of either system");
        }
    }



}

}





#define LENGTH 1000u

int main() {

typedef char user_Input_Stream;
char lol = '\0';

user_Input_Stream arabToRomanString[LENGTH] = { '\0' };
user_Input_Stream numberInput[LENGTH] = { '\0' };
size_t counter = 0;

bool userEnd = false;

while ((lol != EOF) && (userEnd == false))
{
    counter = 0;
    printString(&numberInput);
    resetString(&numberInput);
    resetString(&arabToRomanString);
    counter = 0;
    printString(&numberInput);

    ARABIC_NUM = 0;

    printf("\n\n||Beta version, remember to not mix number systems yet||\n");

    //Repeats until variable lol countains EOF or until boolean holds a true value
    while ((lol != EOF) && (lol != '\n') && (userEnd == false))
    {

        //gets characters, assigns string with them. Gets rid of newline and stores string in array in uppercase
        lol = getchar();

        numberInput[counter] = toupper(lol);
        userEnd = ifEnd(numberInput, counter);
        counter++;
    }


    //TESTING Travels  through String and outputs cells contents. Also, sets boolean to True if user writes END
    for (size_t i = 0; i < counter; i++) {

        if (numberInput[i] == '\n')
        {
            lol = '\\';
            numberInput[i] = toupper(lol);
        }
        // printf("| [%zu] = %c |", i, numberInput[i]);    
    }

    findNumSystem(numberInput, arabToRomanString);
    printf("\n");

}

printf("\n");

return 0;
}
```

Does anyone have an idea of what the issue could be? (ARABIC_NUM is a global variable, the name is to make it easier for me to find for now.)

Comment: Maybe it shouldn't as `IVIV` isn't a valid roman number. If you wanted 44 that is `XLIV`

Comment: @CraigEstey  Lol yeah, I know.  But I have to follow my teacher's instructions for now. He wants **IVIV** to work like an addition and give an output of 4.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: You have `if (strcmp(userString[++localIndex],'V')) {`.  There are multiple problems with that.  The compiler should be complaining about converting an integer to a pointer (use double quotes around the `V`).  If you fixed that, you're looking at the string `"VIV"`, you get a non-zero result from `strcmp()`.  You should use the same `==` and character constant.  You're also incrementing `localIndex` too often if the `if` fails.

Comment: Repeated use of `userString[localIndex++] ==` keeps incrementing the index before you find a match. Rewrite your code without any `++` to get the logic correct. You can put it back later.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I added **strcmp()** as a bad attempt to fix the issue lol, I'll change it back.  I was under the impression the line **localIndex++;** inside the if-statements wouldn't be a problem because the statements shouldn't increment **localIndex** unless their corresponding if-statement is accessed.

Comment: @EricPostpischil So does that mean the conditions inside of if-statements **else if (userString[++localIndex] == 'X')** change variables like a any normal line of code would?

Comment: Yes; the increments are evaluated regardless of whether the condition is true.  If there was an increment on the RHS of an `&&` or `||` operator (or in the second or third parts of a ternary operator), then those increments may or may not be evaluated.  But, with simple conditions like yours, the increments are always evaluated.

Comment: "but then it skips the inner If-Statement" Think carefully about the logic of the code. Before `else if (userString[++localIndex] == 'X')` can be tested, `if (userString[++localIndex] == 'V')` must be tested first, right? Do you expect both of these to use the same value of `localIndex`? Why? (Hint: what does `++localIndex` mean?)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thanks. I was under the impression that conditions for if-statements wouldn't modify variables until Jonathan clarified it for me.

Comment: It's not about the statement, it's about the expression. This is the same reason that people advise writing things like `if (0 == x)`, because then you will get a compiler error if you mistype `=` for `==`, rather than an unintended side effect. This has actually caused security holes in operating systems before (perhaps intentionally). It's also the same reason that some other programming languages make a strong distinction between statements and expressions.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I'll keep that in mind, thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case this might help somebody else, here's the solution I came up with using some of the pointers people in the comment section gave me. It was fairly simple:

I was under the impression that expressions within if-statements don't affect any variables they reference, but in reality they do.

```
For example: if(userString[localIndex] == 'I' && userString[localIndex++] == 'X')
```

In the line above, I was expecting the program to check both the current index and the next upcoming index, which it did but the expression **userString[localIndex++]** within the if-statement also permanently incremented my **localIndex** variable when I wasn't expecting that change to exist outside of the if-statement's parenthesis. So, my program would check the wrong indexes after the first comparison was made and thus why it gave me the wrong output.

To solve this, I created the variable **nextIndex** and used it to store the value **localIndex +1** meaning it will always represent the index after **localIndex**. So, It now works as intended.

Below is what my program looks like now. (I moved around the if and if-else statements for better readability but the only changed that solved my predicament was the addition of **nextIndex**)

```
void convertToArabic(char* userString, size_t counter) {

size_t nextIndex = 0;

for (size_t localIndex = 0; localIndex < findStringLength(userString); localIndex++) {

       // printf("[ %c%s]", userString[localIndex], "-o ");

    nextIndex = localIndex+1;

        if (userString[localIndex] == 'M') {
            ARABIC_NUM += 1000;
        }
        else if (userString[localIndex] == 'C' && userString[nextIndex] == 'M') {
            ARABIC_NUM += 900;
            localIndex++;
        }
        else if (userString[localIndex] == 'D') {
            ARABIC_NUM += 500;
        }
        else if (userString[localIndex] == 'C' && userString[nextIndex] == 'D') {
            
            ARABIC_NUM += 400;
            localIndex++;
        }
        else if(userString[localIndex] == 'C'){
            ARABIC_NUM += 100;
        }
        else if (userString[localIndex] == 'X' && userString[nextIndex] == 'C') {
            ARABIC_NUM += 90;
            localIndex++;
        }
        else if (userString[localIndex] == 'L') {
            ARABIC_NUM += 50;
        }
        else if (userString[localIndex] == 'X' && userString[nextIndex] == 'L'){
            ARABIC_NUM += 40;
            localIndex++;
        }
        else if (userString[localIndex] == 'X') {
            ARABIC_NUM += 10;
        }
        else if ((userString[localIndex] == 'I') && (userString[nextIndex] == 'X')) {
            //localIndex--;
            ARABIC_NUM += 9;
            localIndex++;
        }
        else if (userString[localIndex] == 'V') {
            ARABIC_NUM += 5;
        }
        else if ((userString[localIndex] == 'I') && (userString[nextIndex] == 'V')) {
            //localIndex--;
            printf("Made it in");
            ARABIC_NUM += 4;
            localIndex++;
        }
        else if (userString[localIndex] == 'I') {
            ARABIC_NUM += 1;
        }
         
        
   

    /* else
     {
         printf("[ %c%s]", userString[localIndex],"-x ");
     }*/
    
}

printf("%s%d%s", "\n Number was :", ARABIC_NUM, "\n");
}
```